# BWAPP html injection on level high

Tags: web-application, php, injection

I am trying to bypass `GET HTML injection` in [Buggy Web App (BWAPP)](http://www.itsecgames.com). Payload from input field is printed to HTML after submitting.

- **Low security level** can be bypassed just by simple html payload into fields.
- **Medium security level** can be bypassed by URL encoding of string containing html tag.

However **High security level** has this form of validation:

```
<?php

function xss_check_3($data, $encoding = "UTF-8"){ 
    return htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_QUOTES, $encoding);
}

print xss_check_3($data);

?>
```

It is possible to bypass this kind of validation? Can't think of any possible scenario how to proceed.

Comment: This question is a little undefined. "Is it possible to solve a challenge?" The answer is likely 'yes'. If you are asking *how* to solve the challenge, then we are not going to do this challenge for you. Tell us what you have tried and what you might think work.

Comment: Your update is exactly what I said we would not answer.

Comment: @schroeder sir I have been trying it for past 2 days and I have been reading how htmlspecialchars() works so Its basically encoding <, >, ', & characters and if we will double encode the payload than too it will not accept. I have tried using <h1>hello</h1%> but still it not worked. Please give a small hint to bypass this high level. Thanks you.

Comment: Could someone share a few hints? I don't know where to start

Comment: @schroeder I found a similar topic. Perhaps you should look it up and possibly close https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/175943/how-to-bypass-htmlentities-function-in-php-to-get-an-xss